# Mongoose advanced schema / dynamic "settings" field based on other filed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dynamic, schema

Im trying to create a dynamic mongoose schema.
The parent schema is a "interface". This has two fields: "type" & "settings".

Based on the "type" filed i need to create/assign/validate the "settings" field.

```js
const ENUM_SETTINGS = {
    "RS232": new mongoose.Schema({
        baudRate: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        dataBits: {
            type: Number,
            default: 8
        },
        stopBits: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        },
        parity: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['none', 'even', 'mark', 'odd', 'space'],
            default: "none"
        },
        rtscts: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        xon: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        xoff: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        xany: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    }),
    "ETHERNET": new mongoose.Schema({
        host: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        port: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        path: {
            type: String,
            default: "/"
        },
        protocol: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ["ws", "http", "tcp", "udp"]
        }
    })
};
```

```js
const interfaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: Object.keys(ENUM_SETTINGS)
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    adapter: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Adapters",
        //required: true
    },
    settings: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: true,
        // ... ENUM_SETTINGS based on type value
    }
}, {
    strict: false
});
```

If the "type" fieled on the "interfaceSchema" is "ETHERNET", the `ENUM_SETTINGS["ETHERNET"]` schould be used as "settings" field.

Same applies for "RS232", then 
`ENUM_SETTINGS["RS232"]` should be used

The reason why i want to use a schema is, that it hast build-in validators and i dont need to check it in custom validators or my Business logic.

What i read in the mongoose docs, when my schema is created, its too late to do something like that...

Is there a workaround or elegant way to validate my `ENUM_SETTINGS[<type>]` schema with the given data in ìnterface.settings ?

Comment: Hi @Marc not sure you know Joi. If not , you can check it out here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi . It really helps in validation fields based on values in another and whole bunch of other stuff

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i didnt tought about it. Looks good, so i could create a hapi schema and validate it in a custom "settings" validator on the mongoose schema!
Would be a acceptable solution for me, but i still wonder if something like dynamic child schema is possible

Comment: Exactly! Any difficulty you can let me know and I could post an example